# Как сохранить элементы разметки и удалить в localStorage

Tags: javascript

Приложение заметок , надо чтобы сохранялись заметки с введенным текстом в localStorage и если нажимали удалить заметку ,то оно стиралось и в localStorage, попробовал реализовать

**Сам код приложения:**

```
const containerNote = document.querySelector('.note-container')
```

**Массив для сохранения в localStorage**

```
let itemsArray = []
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
```

**Функция создания новой заметки**

```
let createNote = () => {
document.querySelector('.btn-addNote').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let displayNote = `
    <div class="card w-100 mt-5">
        <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="note-date">
                ${time()}
            </div>

            <div class="checkers">
                <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input" class="input-focus mr-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-del" onclick="delNote(this)">Delete button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="w-100" style="border: 0"
            onfocus="addFocusToNote(this)" onblur="removeFocusToNote(this)"
            ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
`
    containerNote.innerHTML += displayNote
    itemsArray.push(displayNote)
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
})
}

    createNote()
```

**Функция для вывода запушенных данных после перезагрузки страницы**

```
    data.forEach(item => {
    createNote(item)
})
```

**Функция которая удаляет заметку ,но не понимаю как удалять каждую сохраненную заметку из localStorage**

```
let delNote = (that) => {
that.closest('div.card').remove()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, тут есть 2 возможных решения вопроса или ты удаляешь все заметки.

```
localStorage.removeItem('items')
```

Или если ты хочешь, удалить часть заметок, а часть осталась, тогда.

```
const items = localStorage.getItem('items') // получаешь заметки.
items.forEach(item) => {
  // что-то с ними делаешь, например удаляешь не нужные заметки.
}
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items)) //кладешь новый массив заметок в localStorage.
```

Тебе стоит в local Storage хранить только описание, нет смысла хранить разметку, если ты можешь её в любой момент генерировать.

```
let ltems = (!localStorage.getItem('items') ? 
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : []);

ltems.forEach(item => {
   let displayNote = `
      <div class="card w-100 mt-5">
        <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="note-date">
            ${time()}
        </div>

        <div class="checkers">
            <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input" class="input-focus mr-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-del" onclick="delNote(this)">Delete button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="w-100" style="border: 0"
        onfocus="addFocusToNote(this)" onblur="removeFocusToNote(this)"
        ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
`
 containerNote.innerHTML += displayNote
  })

  let createNote = () => {
     document.querySelector('.btn-addNote').addEventListener('click', () => {
        items = [...items, 1]
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
     })
  }

createNote()
```

Comment: понятно , но у меня после перезагрузки ,не сохраняются созданные заметки

Comment: Ты же их добавляешь в local Storage, они сохранены там, ты можешь их просто доставать, когда они тебе нужны. Достал, поменял, положил. Если ты достал и поменял, но не положить изменённый массив, сколько заметок так было, столько и останется.

Comment: я добавляю заметки , смотрю в localStorage через application они есть, обновлю браузер исчезают и значения в localStorage и разметка с созданными заметками

Comment: Они не исчезают, ты просто кладешь туда пустой массив.`let itemsArray = []
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))` когда приложение стартует.

Comment: теперь понял , а как исправить чтобы туда не помешался пустой массив ?

Comment: Можно тернарник прилепить, если localStorage не пуст, тогда выгружать. `let itemsArray = localStorage !== null ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : []`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    at main.js:36
(anonymous) @ main.js:36
2main.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'time' before initialization
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: `let itemsArray = (!localStorage.getItem('items')  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [] )`

Comment: в application пишет key -> items , а в value пустой массив ,разметка не сохраняется

Comment: А зачем тебе хранить разметку в массиве? Не проще хранить имя заметки, и при запуске, перебрать массив и каждому элементу вернуть разметку..

Comment: вот это и не очень понимаю как реализовать ?

Comment: Массив [ 1, 1 , 1 , 1], напиши функцию, для каждого элемента вернуть разметку, при клике в массив добавить ещё 1 и тут же сохранить в localStorage или слушатель на закрытие страницы и потом сохранять localStorage